# Email template formula problem

Tags: formula, email-template

I wrote a workflow for email template where I was trying to get this requirement:

```
<<IF user is operation, then "The Contract Manager", 
else, <Current User Name>> has requested  with the following comments:
Please review and take any necessary action.
```

I tried with this:

```
{!IF($User.Username = "operation.con@board.com "," The Contract Manager",User.Name+ " ")}
has requested  with the following comments:Please review and take any necessary action.
```

Problem is I am just getting the user name which is "operation". But it should show The contract Manager when the user is operation . And when it is other user than operation, it should show that user name there.

Comment: is it operation.com or operation?

Comment: NB `operation.com` is not a valid value for the `Username` field.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, It should be operation.con@board.com

Comment: Could Anybody can give me any solution for this please?

Comment: please use [edit] to correct your formula per your penultimate comment; also it should be `$User.name` as the false condition. Also what kind of email template is it - some formulas don't work in HTML email templates. Also - why trailing blank in if condition?

Comment: This is a text email template.  Condition is like if user is operation.con@board.com then The contract Mananger, else current user name and then the wording . Thanks in advance

Comment: (1) Why the trailing space in the condition; (2) Using $User.Username in a formula is problematic as when a sandbox is refreshed, the formula will no longer work as the $User.Username is appended with the sandbox name and will no longer match the condition.  Hierarchical custom settings can be used, or, switch to a CONTAINS function or you can use $User.Alias which will be invariant across PROD/sandbox orgs